# Invoking sagemaker endpoint using AWS-Lamda throwing parameter validation error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I trained an ML model in AWS Sagemaker and created an endpoint. I want to invoke it using AWS-Lambda. My model has 30 predictor variables. So I passed them into test event of Lambda as dict type as mentioned below

```
{
  "Time": "10 ",
  "V1": "1.449043781 ",
  "V2": "-1.176338825 ",
  "V3": "0.913859833 ",
  "V4": "-1.375666655 ",
  "V5": "-1.971383165 ",
  "V6": "-0.629152139 ",
  "V7": "-1.423235601 ",
  "V8": "0.048455888 ",
  "V9": "-1.720408393 ",
  "V10": "1.626659058 ",
  "V11": "1.19964395 ",
  "V12": "-0.671439778 ",
  "V13": "-0.513947153 ",
  "V14": "-0.095045045 ",
  "V15": "0.230930409 ",
  "V16": "0.031967467 ",
  "V17": "0.253414716 ",
  "V18": "0.854343814 ",
  "V19": "-0.221365414 ",
  "V20": "-0.387226474 ",
  "V21": "-0.009301897 ",
  "V22": "0.313894411 ",
  "V23": "0.027740158 ",
  "V24": "0.500512287 ",
  "V25": "0.251367359 ",
  "V26": "-0.129477954 ",
  "V27": "0.042849871 ",
  "V28": "0.016253262 ",
  "Amount": "7.8"
}
```

Now I ran below mentioned code in AWS Lambda

```
import json
import os
import csv
import boto3
import io
import codecs

endpoint_name = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("received event: "+json.dumps(event,indent=2))
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data["Time"]+data["V1"]+data["V2"]+data["V3"]+data["V4"]+data["V5"]+data["V6"]+data["V7"]+data["V8"]+data["V9"]+data["V10"]+data["V11"]+data["V12"]+data["V13"]+data["V14"]+data["V15"]+data["V16"]+data["V17"]+data["V18"]+data["V19"]+data["V20"]+data["V21"]+data["V22"]+data["V23"]+data["V24"]+data["V25"]+data["V26"]+data["V27"]+data["V28"]+data["Amount"]
    payload = payload.split(" ")
    payload = [codecs.encode(i,'utf-8') for i in payload]
    payload=[bytearray(i) for i in payload]
    print(payload)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,ContentType='text/csv',Body=payload)
    print(response)
    result=json.loads(response['Body'].decode())
    pred = int(float(response))
    predicted_label = 'fraud' if pred==1 else 'not fraud'
    return predicted_label
```

This code is throwing below this error

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: [bytearray(b'10'), bytearray(b'1.449043781'), bytearray(b'-1.176338825'), bytearray(b'0.913859833'), bytearray(b'-1.375666655'), bytearray(b'-1.971383165'), bytearray(b'-0.629152139'), bytearray(b'-1.423235601'), bytearray(b'0.048455888'), bytearray(b'-1.720408393'), bytearray(b'1.626659058'), bytearray(b'1.19964395'), bytearray(b'-0.671439778'), bytearray(b'-0.513947153'), bytearray(b'-0.095045045'), bytearray(b'0.230930409'), bytearray(b'0.031967467'), bytearray(b'0.253414716'), bytearray(b'0.854343814'), bytearray(b'-0.221365414'), bytearray(b'-0.387226474'), bytearray(b'-0.009301897'), bytearray(b'0.313894411'), bytearray(b'0.027740158'), bytearray(b'0.500512287'), bytearray(b'0.251367359'), bytearray(b'-0.129477954'), bytearray(b'0.042849871'), bytearray(b'0.016253262'), bytearray(b'7.8')], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

I understand that somehow I need to pass my 30 features into Lambda function such that data type of `payload` is compatible with `ContentType` for `respnse` to work. Can someone please explain how to do it? 
edit: I'm trying this problem by looking at [this](http://%20https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) aws blog. I don't quite understand how the author of above mentioned blog did it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your error is coming from:

```
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,ContentType='text/csv',Body=payload)
```

but just FYI, it's very helpful if when you ask the a question about an exception, you point out the line causing it :)

[The invoke_endpoint() docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint) specify that `Body` has to be:

> bytes or seekable file-like object

and that `Body`

> provides input data, in the format specified in the `ContentType` request header.

Your content type is `text/csv` so the endpoint will be expecting `bytes` which represent a `csv` string. The question then is what is it getting instead that's making it unhappy?

```
payload = data["Time"]+data["V1"]+ ...
```

At this point, `payload` is a string

```
payload = payload.split(" ")
```

Now it's a list of strings

```
payload = [codecs.encode(i,'utf-8') for i in payload]
```

Now it's a list of strings encoded in `utf-8` (this step might be unnecessary)

```
payload=[bytearray(i) for i in payload]
```

Now it's a list of bytearrays.

And that list is what you're passing as `Body`.

So, to get it to work, you'll need to change your logic to:

1. Make your original input into a CSV
2. Convert that CSV into one single byte array
3. Pass that array as part of your invocation

---

A note on style: passing the input *numbers* as strings, with trailing spaces so you can `split(" ")` is pretty hacky. Just pass the input as plain numbers (remove the `"` surrounding them), and find a way to do what you need with appending then splitting (these are effectively inverse operations, they cancel each other out).